# Horror movie 60's-70's man feeds guests to cave monster

Tags: story-identification, horror, b-movies

Does anyone remember this one? A man with a house or maybe hotel near deep natural cavern system (like Carlsbad). A woman shows up (looking for someone that disappeared?), and gets captured (and abused?). The man's wife tells the woman her own story; the man is shown in flashbacks horrifically abusing his wife (mostly psychological abuse, like surprising her with a dead rat on a covered plate). The monster is some kind of primitive human/missing link (?) that the man discovered in the cave. The man has been caring for it and feeding people to it. It's never really shown, just it's glowing eyes. I don't remember the end except that the cave monster is implied to still be alive.

It was a "B" movie from the early 70's, maybe late 60's. Definitely a movie, not TV. It was filmed in color not BW.

Comment: Based on the description, I'm willing to bet that this film didn't win any Oscars.

Comment: No, but it scared the crap out of me when I was a kid. It scared me again when I when on a school trip to a cave; there was this horrible slurping noise every now and again. The guide didn't explain until he turned the lights out (and I was about to jump out of my skin) that they had to run a sump-pump because of the recent rains.

Comment: A B-Movie / monster movie from the 70's... thats gonna be a tricky one! Do you see the monster at any stage?

Comment: I don't think it's ever really shown, just the glowing eyes.

Comment: I'm beginning to think I'm somehow combining "Whatever Happened to Baby Jane" with "Trog", both starring Joan Crawford.

Comment: @JoeL. Judging by the plot synopses of those two films, it does look like they are what you were thinking about.  Are they? If so are you going to add that as an answer?

Comment: I've been trying to find this movie forever. It scared me as a kid. I do remember the woman trying to escape and the man catches her and whips her with a belt. At one point, he has her locked in a room and serves her a dead rat on a tray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joe, I have been looking for this movie off and on for the past few years.  And thanks to your better description, I have finally found it!  Make no mistake, this is the one.  And it's pretty bad, too!  (haha)  YouTube is your friend.

[It's Alive! (1969)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063145/)

Comment: That's it, alright! I misremembered a lot of things, but I definitely remember the main bad guy.